# request has invalid signature: TSIG rndc-test-key: tsig verify failure (BADKEY)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, keys, nsupdate

I am pretty much new to bind DNS and during nsupdate , i am getting BADKEY error.I have /root/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key as below :-

```
    key "rndc-test-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5 ;
        secret "8d0WLaCU7N/jSyUdjxjAoQ==" ;
} ;
```

and `/etc/rndc.conf`

```
    key "rndc-test-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5 ;
        secret "8d0WLaCU7N/jSyUdjxjAoQ==" ;
} ;
```

In `named.conf   include "/etc/rndc.key"` ;                                               is present.                                                                       So,which key i should pass to ?

Comment: You are speaking of keys which appear to have been set up for the use with `rndc` but you appear to try to use them for some other purpose altogether. Are you positive that it would not make more sense to simply leave rndc and its keys alone (assuming rndc works correctly) and create a new key specific to your other purpose (dynamic updates?).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion gave by "Håkan Lindqvist" and I created just copy the key file in another file called ddns.key and I changed the key name in DDNSKEY. I did this for both named and dhcp.

After this the Dynamic DNS update works.

I still do not understand why reusing the same key/name is breaking the process.